# clang-tidy: `Loop variable is copied but only used as const reference; consider making it a const reference` - does it really matter?

Tags: c++, reference, clang, clang-tidy

I'm working on code that clang-tidy is flagging all over the place with

```
Loop variable is copied but only used as const reference; consider making it a const reference
```

Current code:

```
for (auto foo : collection) {
    ...
}
```

What clang-tidy suggests I use:

```
for (const auto &foo : collection) {
    ...
}
```

I can certainly see where a const reference would be more efficient than actually copying the value, but I'm wondering if the compiler will just optimize it that way anyway? I'd hate to dig in and change hundreds of loops all for nothing.

Comment: *"if the compiler will just optimize it that way anyway"* If you put together a non-trivial test that utilizes both mechanisms and crank up the optimizer, you can test this theory by perusing the asm. I think you'll find it does not (and its right, because it cannot without making some pretty deep assumptions about no side effects from construction, copying, etc.).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Constructors can have side-effects beyond constructing the new object. The semantics of the two versions could therefore differ.

Even if that is not the case, the compiler might not be able to determine that during compilation. For example if the copy constructor of the `foo` type is not defined in the same translation unit and no link-time optimization is used, the compiler wouldn't be able to optimize away the copy, since it might have side-effects that are unknown at compilation time of the current translation unit.

Similarly the loop body might call functions for which the compiler cannot prove that they don't modify `foo`, in which case the copy can also not be optimized away.

(This is by the way harder for the compiler to prove than it is for clang-tidy to give you the warning, since even a function taking a `const` reference of `foo` is technically still allowed to modify it. And even if the `foo` object itself is `const`-qualified (e.g. `const auto`), functions may depend on the address of the `foo` object being different than that of the container's `foo` object through other program paths.)

Even if everything is visible in the translation unit and the observable behavior doesn't depend on the copy, the operations might be too complex for the compiler to optimize the copy away.

---

Example:

```
auto f(const std::vector<std::string>& x) {
    std::size_t n = 0;
    for(auto y : x)
        n += y.size();
    return n;
}
```

Both GCC and Clang with `-O3` and libstdc++ don't optimize the copies away (see the `operator new`/`operator delete`/`memcpy` calls in the assembly): https://godbolt.org/z/d66ac617M

Also compare to the same code with references instead: https://godbolt.org/z/Tdc3GhcEv

---

However, in the above example there might still be a visibility issue with the standard library implementation of `std::string`. Here is maybe a better example in which all definitions are probably visible in the current translation unit:

```
struct A { int a[64]; };

auto f(const std::vector<std::vector<A>>& x) {
    std::size_t n = 0;
    for(auto y : x)
        n += y.size();
    return n;
}
```

In this case, GCC still doesn't optimize the copy away, while Clang does, although it still leaves some allocation size check in there for some reason: https://godbolt.org/z/8KWPTx4o5

But if the type is made more complex there will probably be a point at which neither compiler will be able to optimize away the copy even though everything is visible.

---

If you know that the type of `foo` is simple, e.g. a scalar like on a `std::vector<int>` container, then it doesn't really matter in terms of performance, assuming the observable behavior is the same.

You might still want to use the `const` reference, more specifically the `const` part, for the purpose of keeping const-correctness throughout your code. How necessary that is, probably goes into opinion-based territory though.

Comment: Thank you; very good answer. Never heard of godbolt.org before; that looks like a useful tool. Looks like I'll go back and take clang-tidy's advice.

Comment: Disagree with the comment at the end. Even if it’s a scalar, or a trivially copyable type, const correctness matters. It tells both the compiler and future code readers you don’t want to/intend to modify anything.

Comment: @Taekahn I have expanded my comment.